# Unexpected result from simple convolution with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have not done DSP in a while but I hand't expected my grasp of the basics to slip this far.
I have a script where I am convolving a tone with a complex exponential.  The result of which I expect to be a shifted tone.  My result is quite unexpected - I am getting 3 tones and none of them are at the frequency I expect.  Can someone explain why I'm getting these results?

Here is the script.

```
import sys
import numpy
import math
import scipy
from pylab import *

def gen_tone(f, fs, length):
    t = linspace(0, length, length * fs)
    return cos(2.0 * pi * f * t)

def gen_exp(f, fs, length):
    t = linspace(0, length, length * fs)
    return numpy.exp(1.0j * 2 * pi * f * t)

def plot_fft(f, fs):
    FFT = abs(scipy.fft(f, 1024)) / f.size
    figure()
    plot(FFT)

f100 = gen_tone(8000, 44100, 1)
f200j = gen_exp(1000, 44100, 1)

res = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(f100, f200j, 'full')

plot_fft(f100, 44100)
plot_fft(f200j, 44100)
plot_fft(res, 44100)

show()
```

Comment: what do you expect as result (the freq i mean)? and what do you get as freqs?

Comment: It's as warren's answer says: you convolved your functions, instead of multiplying them. Multiply by complex exponential --> frequency shift.

Comment: Yeah - that was pretty fail on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *frequency shift property*. (See, e.g. http://ocw.usu.edu/Electrical_and_Computer_Engineering/Signals_and_Systems/5_6node6.html; scroll down a bit to the section labeled *Frequency-shift Property*.)  That is, if the Fourier transform of `f(t)` is `F(w)`, then the Fourier transform of `f(t)*exp(j*w0*t)` is `F(w - w0)`.  The expression `f(t)*exp(j*w0*t)` is point-wise multiplication of `f(t)` and `exp(j*w0*t)`, *not* convolution.

To see the result that you expected, replace this:

```
res = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(f100, f200j, 'full')
```

with

```
res = f100 * f200j
```

The result is easier to see if you modify your plot function as follows:

```
def plot_fft(f, fs):
    FFT = abs(fft(f, 1024)) / f.size
    freq = fftfreq(1024, 1.0/fs)
    ndx = freq.argsort()
    figure()
    plot(freq[ndx], FFT[ndx])
    grid(True)
```

and add

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq
```

at the top of your script.

You'll see that the peaks at -8000 and 8000 in the FFT plot of `f100` are shifted to -7000 and 9000 in FFT plot of `res`.

Comment: So would the operation I did be equivalent to time shifting the signal?  I'm looking at the time shift rule.  It results in multiplication in the frequency domain by a complex exponential which is equal to convolution in the time domain.

Comment: Convolution in the time domain corresponds to point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain.  That's why you got three peaks, at -8000, 8000 and 1000.  If you scroll up a bit in the link I mentioned above, you'll see a description of the "Time shift Property", which says that point-wise multiplication in the frequency domain by the complex exponential `exp(-j*w*t0)` gives a shift of `t0` in the time domain.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a multiplication in the frequency domain (shifted tone), so you must do that:

```
res = f100 * f200j
```

instead of

```
res = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(f100, f200j, 'full')
```

Below is the picture of the spectrum (not the FFT) of the `input` (black) and the `res` (blue) signal. The shifted signal shows a dirac at 9kHz (8000 up shifted of 1000).
[image]

and here below is my plotSpectrum function

```
def plotSpectrum(y,Fs):
    """
    Plots a Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)
    """
    n = len(y) # length of the signal
    k = arange(n)
    T = n/Fs
    frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
    frq = frq[arange(int(n/2))] # one side frequency range

    Y = fft(y)/n # fft computing and normalization
    Y = Y[arange(int(n/2))]

    plot(frq,abs(Y),'r') # plotting the spectrum
    xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
    ylabel('|Y(freq)|')
```